# Amazon DynamoDB - Scanning Itens using JS

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I've have tried to scan a table and filter it by its secondary key, which is Number named Group. If I applied this sacn at Amazon Web Console, the result is simple and right:
[image]

But using JavaScript I only got an empty result. Here is the JS code:

```
var id;
console.log("scan products")
// Get the id from the pathParams
id = request.pathParams.id;
console.log(id)
var params = {
    TableName: request.env.tableName,
    FilterExpression: '#product_group = :this_group',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {':this_group': {N:id}},
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {'#product_group':'group'}
};
console.log("aqui")
console.log(params.ExpressionAttributeValues)
// post-process dynamo result before returning
return dynamo.scan(params).promise().then(function (response) {
    return response;
});
```

Here you can see my result output:

```
2018-01-04T16:53:38.223Z ce022431-f16f-11e7-8a90-4f25e3228700 { headers:
{ 'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '40',
connection: 'close',
date: 'Thu, 04 Jan 2018 16:53:38 GMT',
'x-amzn-requestid': 'ce6663b2-f16f-11e7-913f-c1a766cd30ad',
'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
'access-control-allow-headers': 'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET,OPTIONS',
'x-amzn-trace-id': 'sampled=0;root=1-5a4e5c10-f5dbe9d3ad72eb4f1f5bdc12',
'access-control-max-age': '0',
'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
'x-cache': 'Miss from cloudfront',
via: '1.1 aa9a6b87feabe1a30d21428a24c1a7d8.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
'x-amz-cf-id': 'AvS-yi8Y_-b6nwyYNosEGxpvpBkMptFigjldwZmO3ros6kO8JdBZhQ==' },
body: '{"Items":[],"Count":0,"ScannedCount":14}',
statusCode: 200,
statusMessage: 'OK' }
```

I don't know what I'm possible doing wrong since it is a really simple scan.

Answer (score 0):

Please scan until the `LastEvaluatedKey` is null to go through all the items in the Dynamodb table. The single scan will go through only **1 MB** of data.

Please execute the scan until `LastEvaluatedKey` is null.

> A single Scan operation will read up to the maximum number of items
>   set (if using the Limit parameter) or a maximum of 1 MB of data and
>   then apply any filtering to the results using FilterExpression. If
>   LastEvaluatedKey is present in the response, you will need to paginate
>   the result set.

[API Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)

[Scan table - sample code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html)

**Note the below code:-**

The scan should be executed until LastEvaluatedKey is undefined or null.

```
if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
            console.log("Scanning for more...");
            params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
            docClient.scan(params, onScan);
        }
```

Comment: In this case, my table has 14 elements so I think that it scanned all of them and still finding any "match".

Comment: what are you getting for console.log for id?

Comment: 17:37:03
2018-01-04T17:37:03.828Z e076a96a-f175-11e7-8580-891e9ea1e5ef 3

17:37:03
2018-01-04T17:37:03.828Z e076a96a-f175-11e7-8580-891e9ea1e5ef aqui

17:37:03
2018-01-04T17:37:03.967Z e076a96a-f175-11e7-8580-891e9ea1e5ef { ':this_group': { N: '3' } }

Maybe it is not clear, but i'm receiving 3.

Comment: Looks like you have cloudfront for the web service (based on your output) ? If yes, please check the cache setting.

Comment: this is something i'm not sure because I'm using claudiajs as serverless framework. But i'll check.

Comment: Ok. I looked at cloudfront and there aren't any configurations or services being used there.